# How can i change text depending on the date in another cell Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to make a cell change its text depending on another cell whit a date.
[example how i would like the text to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAaop.png)

So basicly if there is one week past from today the text green needs to change in the text red. Is this possible? If so how beacuse im lost.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv1wf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit text

1. Be sure that the cell value is formatted as Date (Format>Number>Date)
2. Put this formula in column A and drag it down to match your dates:

```
=IF(B2<TODAY()-6, "Red", "Green")
```

### Edit background color

1. Be sure that the cell value is formatted as Date (Format>Number>Date)
2. Create a Conditional formatting rule (Right-click>Conditional Formatting) with these parameters:

Format cells if...

- Date is before
- Exact date
- =TODAY()-6

Formatting style

- Put desired background color

### Reference

[Conditional Formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: Hey thank you for the awsner! But this is not exactly what i mean. I want to change the text not the Background color.

Comment: Hey thanks for you awsner! When i try the formula that your provided i get an error. I added a screenshot to the post so you can see the error. Am i doing anyting wrong?

Comment: It's probably due to your "locale" settings. If I'm not mistaken you should get it to work by replacing commas "," with semicolons ";" in your formula.

`=IF(B2<TODAY()-6; "Red"; "Green")`

Comment: Hey i have one more question. Is it possible to have more in one cell. So for instance if it is 2 weeks before today to change the color to purple?